# Database Support for Pact Broker

Tags: maven, pact, pact-broker

We are planning to implement customize Pact Broker and implement it as our own application in our workplace rather using any existing docker image.

I know Pact Broker is recommended to use with PostgreSQL and also supports MySQL, but just wanted to understand does Pact Broker supports Oracle DB also as one of its storage source ? And if yes, Could you point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

No sorry, it only supports Postgres and MySQL.